# Data gets deallocated before use with ASIHTTPRequest asynchronous mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest in asynchronous mode in a function called from my viewDidLoad()

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somewebsite.com/data.txt"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

This is my requestFinished() where I do some text replacement and populate an NSArray with the data I've received from the website. It's just text, one data item per line.
The NSArray (and alloc / init) in viedDidLoad().

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSString *sTemp = [request responseString]; 
   sTemp = [sTemp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@","];          
   arrayTidalData = [sTemp componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; 
   NSLog(@"Loaded %d items into the array",[arrayTidalData count]);
   [tableTideTimes reloadData];
}
```

NSLog reports 127 data items.

Now, I use the NSArray data to populate a UITableView.
But, in cellForRowAtIndexPath() when I attempt to access the NSArray (arrayTidalData), for instance by doing a count, I get the following:

TideTimes[14696:b303] *** -[__NSArrayM count]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4e6c6a0

(I turned on NSZOMBIEEnabled = YES to get this data)

It seems the NSArray has been deallocated before I can use it. I also tried populating an NSString with the data in requestFinish() but got the same result.

Am I missing something really simple or am I doing something terribly wrong?

(It's my first time with ASIHTTPRequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
arrayTidalData = [sTemp componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

with

```
arrayTidalData = [[sTemp componentsSeparatedByString:@","] retain];
```

It is because `componentsSeparatedByString:` returns `autoreleased` object. So it is `released` after method `requestFinished:` ends working.

And don't forget to release at the end of work (for example, `dealloc`).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of adding the retain at all.
Fantastic!